# Can ASP.NET ImageHandler output contents of a Url

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, httphandler

I have an asp.net web forms application that uses an ImageHandler to output images. Basically to prevent leeching but also to get image files from another server.

Here's the implementation of ProcessRequest:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext ctx)
    {
        HttpRequest req = ctx.Request;
        string path = req.PhysicalPath.ToLower();
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(path);

        if (req.UrlReferrer != null && req.UrlReferrer.Host.Length > 0)
        {
            if (CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo.Compare(req.Url.Host, req.UrlReferrer.Host, CompareOptions.IgnoreCase) != 0)
            {
                path = ctx.Server.MapPath("~/images/noimage.jpg");
            }
        } 

        // Rewrite path if not in production
        if (imagePath != null)
        {
            if (path.Length > path.IndexOf("\\images\\", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 7)
            {
                string end = path.Substring(path.IndexOf("\\images\\", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 7);
                path = string.Concat(imagePath, end).Replace("\\", "/");
            }
        }

        string contentType;

        switch (extension)
        {
            case ".gif":
                contentType = "image/gif";
                break;
            case ".jpg":
                contentType = "image/jpeg";
                break;
            case ".png":
                contentType = "image/png";
                break;
            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException("Unrecognized image type.");
        }

        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            ctx.Response.Status = "Image not found";
            ctx.Response.StatusCode = 404;
        }
        else
        {
            ctx.Response.StatusCode = 200;
            ctx.Response.ContentType = contentType;
            ctx.Response.WriteFile(path);
        }
    }
```

The above code fails because I want to rewrite the path to a url not a file path. The reason I want to rewrite is because the actual image files is on another server and is not accessible via UNC paths. What am I doing wrong, and is it possible at all to accomplish this?

Cheers

Comment: If I understand your scenario correctly, you could possible use WebClient class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx  to make an HTTP request for your image on the external server and then send that in your response to the client. That way the actual URL of the image will be invisible to the end user, and you don't have the restriction of having to use a UNC path.

Comment: Actually I found another solution to the problem. At the end of rewriting the path, I call Response.Redirect. There, problem solved. Thanks for the input guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are on the call for this handler - then you do not have any more the ability to rewrite your path as I see that you try to do.

The rewrite path is to say to IIS and asp.net that a call for example to `http://www.url.com/one/page1.aspx` is served by the `http://www.url.com/someotherpage.aspx?id=one`

You are all ready not on the final processing of your data, there you must read the file and send it to the browser, for example as:

```
 public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
      // your first code
      // ...
       if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            ctx.Response.Status = "Image not found";
            ctx.Response.StatusCode = 404;
        }
        else
        {
            // load here the image 
            ....
            // and send it to browser
            ctx.Response.OutputStream.Write(imageData, 0, imageData.Length);
        }
    }
```